# Example for deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, deprecation-warning

I get the following deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changed?` 
inside of after callbacks will be changing 
in the next version of Rails. 
The new return value will reflect the behavior 
of calling the method after `save` returned 
(e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). 
To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_changes?` instead.
```

for this code:

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  # If the record is new or changed then delay the
  # delivery until the after_commit callback otherwise
  # send now because after_commit will not be called.
  if new_record? || changed?
    pending_notifications << [notification, args]
  else
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end
end
```

**Can somebody explain me the Deprecation Warning with an example?** I'm not sure if I understand correctly what's meant with `The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after "save" returned`

Can I now simply replace `changed?` with `saved_changes?`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it works like this. Now `#changed?` returns `false` in after callbacks until you change an attribute. So `#changed?` on a record behave in after callbacks as if you've just fetched a record by doing `#find` (or, as the message says, if you have a record after calling `#save`). `#saved_changes?` answers the question: did the last call to `#save` have any changes to change? So in the cases I can think of you can safely switch to this method in after callbacks.